# Angular unable to access root scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to created an init function, when I register my angular app :

```
//Register main app
var fertiliserCaculator = angular.module('fertiliserCalculator',['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {

 console.log($rootScope)
 }]);
```

This returns an `$injector:modulerr`, what is the correct way to define a controller-type function for the main App name space?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

- Create your module:

`var fertiliserCaculator = angular.module('fertiliserCalculator', []);`

- Create a controller:

`fertiliserCaculator.controller('fertiliserCaculatorController', function($scope, $rootScope){
    console.log($rootScope);
    $scope.foo = 'Yolo!';
});`

- Use your controller in a simple app:

  `<body ng-app="fertiliserCalculator">
     <div ng-controller="fertiliserCaculatorController">{{$scope.foo}}</div>
  </body>`

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it the run function is the first runtime function to be called be angular app start

```
//Register main app
var fertiliserCaculator = angular.module('fertiliserCalculator',[]);

fetiliserCalculator.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
  console.log($rootScope)
}]);
```

Comment: I get `fetiliserCalculator is not defined` when I add this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [guide/module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), module method doesn't take a function in is second argument but a list of modules.

You have to create a controller in this module (like [guide/controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)):

```
// declare a module
  var calculatorApp = angular.module('fertiliserCalculator', []);

  calculatorApp.filter('greet', function() {
   return function(name) {
      return 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
    };
  });

  calculatorApp.controller('fooCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
     $scope.foo = 'youhou';
  }]);
```

Without forget to add ng-controller to your html

```
  <div ng-controller="fooCtrl">
      {{ foo | greet }}
  </div>
```

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNZrGlcZUmHrow37KQe2?p=preview) for you base on AngularJS doc